# Loading image using pug, js, json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, image, pug

I'm having some problems with a full responsive and autogenerated pug and js page, I use js files to pass JSON data to the pug page, the pug page load everithing correctly but not the image (the image is a url). What can i do to make it load? Here's the code:
pug:

```
block content
 html
  head
    title #{title}
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/style.css')
    meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1")
  body
    header.header
          h1 #{title}
    each person in p
      div.person
        div.person-image
         img(src=('/${person.image}') top center no-repeat;) 
        a(href=`/user/poeti/person?name=${person.name}`)
         h2 #{person.name}
```

js:

```
router.get('/poeti/person', function(req,res,next){
    const person = people.find((m) => m.name === req.query.name);;
    res.render('poeti', {
    title: person.name,
    pt: person
  });
});
-----------------------------------------------------------------
router.get('/new', function(req, res, next) {
 res.send(createFakePerson());
});
-----------------------------------------------------------------
function createFakePerson()
{
 people.json=new Object;
 let person;
 let vett = new Array();
 let texts = new Array();
 var i;
 for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let randomName = faker.name.findName(); // random name
  let randomEmail = faker.internet.email(); // random mail
  for (n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
   let randomText = faker.lorem.text(); // random text
   texts.push(randomText)
  }
  let randomCountry = faker.address.country() // random country
  let randomWebSite = faker.internet.url() // random website
  let randomProfile = faker.image.avatar() //random people image

  person = {
   name:randomName,
   email:randomEmail,
   text:texts,
   nazionality: randomCountry,
   website: randomWebSite,
   image: randomProfile
 }
 vett.push(person)
}

 let data = JSON.stringify(vett);
 fs.writeFileSync('people.json', data);
 return vett;
}
```

JSON (this is a shorter example of my json file):

```
[{
name: Pippo
email: Pippo@mail.com
text:[random texts]
image: https://randomimage
},{other random peoples}]
```

Now, how can i make pug show my image at url https://randomimage? (in this case the image doesn't exist, this is only an example) if you need to know anything else in order to help just let me know.

P.S. I'm using a library called faker.js that let me generate random information.

Comment: i only gave a short json since you can see how i create it in the function createFakePerson()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `person.find` function will return only a single record from an array of people. So the statement `each person in p` in your pug will just iterate over the object's attributes and not an array of persons. You can make these changes in your `pug` code to the show the image.

```
...
...
  body
    header.header
      h1 #{title}
      //each person in p
      div.person
        div.person-image
          img(src=p.image top center no-repeat) 
          a(href=`/user/poeti/person?name=${p.name}`) Link
          h2 #{p.name}
```

Comment: Thnx, now it works, i modified a bit the code, i simply put the img part of your code and adapted to mine since i still have to cycle trought the json array, but now it works